# jQuery: What listener do I use to check for browser auto filling the password input field?

Tags: jquery, forms, autocomplete, input, listener

I have a simple problem that I cannot seem to find a solution to.

Basically on this website here: http://dev.supply.net.nz/vendorapp/ (currently in development)
I have some fancy `label` animations sliding things in and out on `focus` & `blur`.

However once the user has logged in once the browser will most likely remember the password associated with the users email address/login. (Which is good and should not be disabled.)

However I run into issues triggering my `label` slide out animation when the browser sets the value on the `#password` field automatically as the event for this is neither `focus` nor `blur`.

Does anyone know which listener to use to run my function when the browser 'auto fills' the users password?

Here is a quick screenshot of the issue:

[Password Autofill Label Issue http://dl.dropbox.com/u/376243/fill_issue.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/376243/fill_issue.png)

Comment: Just as a matter of personal preference, I really dislike sites that fill in the fields with some grayed out "Enter password" or the like. It has difficulty with browser auto complete like you mentioned, but also with external programs (like KeePass which I use a lot). At my last job we did a kind of usability study for things of this nature, just for internal apps, and usually people don't care, and sometimes (like in my case) they dislike it. I would suggest something of that nature before bogging the page down with events and handlers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recently read an article called [Capturing AutoFill as a Change Event](http://furrybrains.com/2009/01/02/capturing-autofill-as-a-change-event/) that just may be what you're looking for. The author created a function called `listenForChange()` that monitors a field for form autofilling activity (is autofilling even a word?). Since it checks your form really frequently I personally suggest you to only run this a certain number of times. After all a form auto-fill will usually do its work as soon as the page has finished loading.

Quoting the original article:

> *The plugin makes use of the trigger() and data() functions. In a nutshell,
>   we loop over the input element or set
>   of children input elements, storing
>   their initial value in the data cache
>   provided by the data() function. We
>   then check to see if the stored value
>   matches the value of the input during
>   the current iteration. If so, we do
>   nothing, if not, we manually fire the
>   change event via trigger(). There’s
>   also a bit of logic in there to ignore
>   the element that has focus. We don’t
>   need to worry about this element,
>   since if the value is changed while
>   the user has focus, the change event
>   will be fired as normal when the
>   element is blurred.*

And here's the function itself incase you don't want to go and read the article (which you should):

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.listenForChange = function(options) {
        settings = $.extend({
            interval: 200 // in microseconds
        }, options);

        var jquery_object = this;
        var current_focus = null;

        jquery_object.filter(":input").add(":input", jquery_object).focus( function() {
            current_focus = this;
        }).blur( function() {
            current_focus = null;
        });

        setInterval(function() {
            // allow
            jquery_object.filter(":input").add(":input", jquery_object).each(function() {
                // set data cache on element to input value if not yet set
                if ($(this).data('change_listener') == undefined) {
                    $(this).data('change_listener', $(this).val());
                    return;
                }
                // return if the value matches the cache
                if ($(this).data('change_listener') == $(this).val()) {
                    return;
                }
                // ignore if element is in focus (since change event will fire on blur)
                if (this == current_focus) {
                    return;
                }
                // if we make it here, manually fire the change event and set the new value
                $(this).trigger('change');
                $(this).data('change_listener', $(this).val());
            });
        }, settings.interval);
        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

All credit goes to the owner of FurryBrains.com for writing the article.

Comment: This is awesome. just the thing i needed. Thanks. Edit: Read the article. Good read, valuable information

Comment: Auto-fill does not always occur on load. For example, the password can be auto-filled when the user enters his name.

Answer (score 0):

Also you should probably also put a listener on change:

```
$('#password').change(function() {
    // DEAL WITH IT IF THERE IS CONTENT IN IT AND THE LABEL IS STILL THERE
});
```

Comment: Pretty sure `.change` requires user interaction giving focus to that particular element. It's not constantly monitoring the value.

Answer (score -1):

You'll have to manually fire the event in your .ready()

```
var $p = $('#password');
if($p.val() != '') {
  $('#password').focus();
}
```

Comment: what if the initial value isn't an empty string?

Comment: @PeteMontgomery not everytime. If you have multiple accounts you can autofill multiple times with different values. The username/password case is also an intersting case.