# JavaScript change input color after entry

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am currently using this script and will love to extend it to change the color of the fields that have been filled. Can you help out please?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").focus(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color","#cccccc");
     });

    $("input").blur(function(){
     $(this).css("background-color","#ffffff");
     });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: You would need to define what "filled-out" means.  It sounds like you just want to have a different condition in your onblur handler to where it is one color if the field is still empty and another if it is "filled out", based on whatever your criteria for "filled out" is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check if the field is filled in on blur:

```
$("input").on('blur', function () {
    if ($(this).val()) {
        $(this).css("background-color","#0f0");
    }
    else {
        $(this).css("background-color","#fff");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

While this is not a "write your script for you" site, you've asked a simple question to which a simple answer can be given. See if you can figure out why this works, and next time, before you ask a question, try and piece together the answer from this and other bits of code you've doubtless found around the web:

```
$("input").change(function(){ // this just checks if there's anything in the field
    if($(this).val().length > 0)) {
        $(this).css("background-color", "green"); // input has been filled
    } else {
        $(this).css("background-color", "red"); // input has not been filled
    }
});
```

Comment: What about it? `$.change()` detects any change in an input's value, wherever that change comes from.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066406/jquery-what-listener-do-i-use-to-check-for-browser-auto-filling-the-password-in

Comment: I see. Well, if the OP wants, he can use the solution put forward in the linked answer. However, I highly suspect `$.change()` will cover his current needs. Thanks for the input!