# How can I detect that a user has filled an input by using a browser's autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have a Log In screen and I disable the Login button until the user has entered their account # and last 4 of their SSN.  It works fine so long as the user manually enters this information.  However, I run into an issue if the user decides to use auto-complete to fill out the form because they must then tab off of the input field in order for it to register that the input has been entered and enable the Login button.

Is there a way I can automatically enable the LogIn button (assuming the data is correct) as soon as the user auto-completes everything?  This is what I have so far:

```
    $("input[type=text], input[type=password]").on("keyup", enableLogIn);
    $("input[type=text], input[type=password]").bind("paste", enableLogIn);

    function enableLogIn() {
        if ($("#AccountNumber").val().length < 6 || $("#SocialSecurityNumber").val().length < 4) {
            $("#loginButton").attr("disabled", true);
        } else {
            $("#loginButton").attr("disabled", false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try with the `change` event.

Comment: I think that also waits for them to tab out.

Comment: The `change` event requires a focus and blur, that won't work.

Comment: You need something that looks at each keystroke as it is typed.

Comment: There's no keystroke when you choose from an autocomplete menu.

Comment: Assuming you are talking about autofill http://stackoverflow.com/a/11710295/1414562

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066406/jquery-what-listener-do-i-use-to-check-for-browser-auto-filling-the-password-in

Comment: fire a custom event on autocomplete.

Comment: @raam86: Naturally.  The question is how.

Comment: @raam86 How? Autocomplete is done internally by the browser.

Comment: He's not using the jQuery UI auto-complete plugin, this is the browser's built-in autofill.

Comment: I think the safest option is autocomplete="off" as roasted mentioned above. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp

Comment: Ah.  The nuclear option.

Comment: @Huangism roasted must have deleted that comment, I don't see it.

Comment: @Barmar i didn't post it as comment but it is what is suggested on link i posted

Comment: He said Assuming you are talking about autofill stackoverflow.com/a/11710295/1414562

Comment: @Barmar: roasted linked a different post than the duplicate.  It suggests turning autofill off and polling the text box for completion.

Comment: Oops, I didn't read all the way through the answer in that question. Seems like the wrong solution, especially since there are browser extensions to override `autofill=off` (I use one of them).

Answer (score 0):

I think the `edit` event will be triggered when the field is modified, without waiting for tabbing out. Also notice that you can give multiple events to `.on`.

```
$("input[type=text], input[type=password]").on("keyup paste input", enableLogIn);
```

However, this is probably browser-dependent, I don't think older browsers have this event.

Comment: What is this event 'edit'? When is it fired? Can find DOC on it. Are you taliking about 'oninput' event?

Comment: @roasted I think he meant the [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/input) event

Comment: You're both right. Fixed.