# jquery change function does not work when fill input from cache

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try do form validator using jquery. Generally everything works except one situation.

I want in any change in input my function checkEmail check is everything is ok. If not color of input is change on red. When i write or paste to input it works but when i choose value from cache (browser give me list of value to choose) my input do not change color.

```
const checkEmail = () => {
if (!validator.isEmail(emailInput.val())) {
    emailInput.removeClass('input-success')
    emailInput.addClass('input-error')
    return false
} else {
    emailInput.removeClass('input-error')
    emailInput.addClass('input-success')
    return true
}
```

}

```
emailInput.change('input', checkEmail);
```

Is any way to trigger a function on really any change? I event try setTimeOut but then it looks like jquery do not see value in my Input.

PS. Im new here please be patience :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery: What listener do I use to check for browser auto filling the password input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066406/jquery-what-listener-do-i-use-to-check-for-browser-auto-filling-the-password-in)

Answer (score 0):

```
emailInput.on('input', checkEmail);
```

here the demo https://jsfiddle.net/kt56opsx/